# Smooth scrolling end positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I have a nifty smooth animated scroll that goes up and down depending on what you click on the navigation (thanks to [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)!). Now this is all working great but I have a nav that sticks to the top of the browser window and gets in the way of the section headers when it scrolls down. I can't for the life of me find anyone who may have had a similar issue with, what seems like, a very simple function.

Here's the JS that I have pasted into my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  function filterPath(string) {
  return string
    .replace(/^\//,'')
    .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
    .replace(/\/$/,'');
  }
  var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
  var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

   $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
    var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
    if (  locationPath == thisPath
    && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
      var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
      if (target) {
        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
        $(this).click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 800, function() {
            location.hash = target;
          });
        });
      }
    }
  });

  // use the first element that is "scrollable"
  function scrollableElement(els) {
    for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
      var el = arguments[i],
          $scrollElement = $(el);
      if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
         return el;
      } else {
        $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
        var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
        $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
        if (isScrollable) {
          return el;
        }
      }
    }
    return [];
  }

});</script>
```

So I am in the process of learning JS and JQuery so I appreciate everyones patience and look forward to hearing your comments.

Many thanks in advance.

Edit: here is my test site: [test](http://www.nathanlangley.co.uk/main_site_6/index.html)

Comment: I don't find the JS you posted very helpful. You mention a nav that gets in the way so what are it's current CSS properties when it is in the way and what (if you know) might be putting it in the way?

Comment: @Matthew Apologies, after hours of looking at code I lost the will to type last night :) here is my test page: nathanlangley.co.uk/main_site_6/index.html as you can see when you select 'Gallery' on the nav the header is partially obscured by the navigation. I am sure there is a value I need to amend but I can't see within this code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a copy of jquery.scrollTo.js 
from http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/09/jqueryscrollto-14-released.html

This is what controls the position of the scroll item

```
 $.scrollTo( 0, 500);
```

the 0 would take to top of the page, if you set higher figure
it would take your lower down the page, in my example I have 5 sections I wanted to scroll to. Change as you need.

I used this in the head section:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
 // scroll to top
 $('a.topOfPage').click(function(){
 $.scrollTo( 0, 500);
 return false;
 });
 // scroll to top
 $('a.twoOfPage').click(function(){
 $.scrollTo( 570, 500);
 return false;
 });
 // scroll to top
 $('a.threeOfPage').click(function(){
 $.scrollTo( 1175, 500);
 return false;
 });
 // scroll to top
 $('a.fourOfPage').click(function(){
 $.scrollTo( 1790, 500);
 return false;
 });
 // scroll to top
 $('a.fiveOfPage').click(function(){
 $.scrollTo( 2385, 500);
 return false;
 });
 });
 </script>
```

In the body section corresponding nav:

```
 <ul class="pagination">

   <li><a href="" class="topOfPage">1</a></li>
   <li><a href="" class="twoOfPage">2</a></li>
   <li><a href="" class="threeOfPage">3</a></li>
   <li><a href="" class="fourOfPage">4</a></li>
   <li><a href="" class="fiveOfPage">5</a></li>

 </ul>
```

If you need more ref I found the original code via
http://nick.boldison.com/websites/jquery/jquery-scroll-to-top-animation-scrollto-plugin/

I hope that helps you.

Cheers
V

Comment: Hey V thanks for your reply. I don't think I am explaining myself very well. If you view my test [site](http://nathanlangley.co.uk/main_site_6/index.html)  and make the browser smaller (assuming you have a larger screen) select 'Testimonials' you'll see what I mean. The scroll works fine but the sticky nav overlays the header.

Comment: Hey - I understand you want the "Titles" to start lower down so the Nav overlay does not overlap them ontop. If so the code above will let you target how far down the page you scroll to. I had the same issue with what I am working on, I have a fixed nav top section like yours, and it would do exactly what your site is doing.

Comment: I have put up the example for you [link](http://www.wonderlandwpa.com/diginate/) and the zip folder [link](http://www.wonderlandwpa.com/diginate/diginate.zip)  with the code used.

Comment: Hey sorry bout the long time to reply, just trying this out now!

Comment: You my friend are a Legend. Worked a treat. Many thanks for taking the time to help me out with that.  Appreciate it! :)